# Is there a way I can get all of the HTML element Ids inside a <div> with Selenium / Web Driver?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath, protractor

I am using Protractor for testing and my test code has code like this:

```
var topic = this;

topic.topicName = element(by.id('topicName'));
topic.topicVersion = element(by.id('topicVersion'));
.....
.....
topic.description = element(by.id('description'));
topic.topicHeader = element(by.id('topicHeader'));
topic.topicFooter = element(by.id('topicFooter'));
```

It was suggested to me that I could simplify this coding by using a forEach by using this function.

```
['topicName', 'topicVersion', ...].forEach(function(k){
    topic[k] = element(by.id(k));
});
```

This looks much cleaner but I am wonder if I could automate this even more so that somehow I have code that collects all of the ID's are inside the following `<div id="adminTopicPage">`.

Using xpath or something similar is it possible for me to automate the collecting of ids inside of this `<div>` and have all of the elements with ids assigned as properties on an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I do not have much knowledge about javascript but my suggest approach as below

1 - You can get all elements from your divelement

```
E.g.:
topic.divAdminTopicPage = element(by.id('adminTopicPage'));
topic.divAdminTopicPageChild1 = topic.divAdminTopicPage.findElement(By.locator);
```

2 - Then you could fetch them into a object as key => value

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I would recommend you to try something like this:

```
$$('#someElement [id]').map(function(elm) {
  return {
    id: elm.getAttribute('id')
  }
}).then(function(ids){
  expect(ids).toEqual([
    {id: 'foo'},
    {id: 'bar'}
  ]);
});
```

Take a look at this example. It is the unit test I wrote when I implemented `map`:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/36e0e0aaf090b0c9b5450fa59ba2da4c4237442a/spec/basic/elements_spec.js#L177